# Lifetime of a Singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, singleton

I'm building a **WCF-Service** which is hosted in a **windows service**. The WCF-Service is called by an ASP.Net application by using a proxy.

```
using (WcfServiceRef.MonitorClient proxy = new WcfServiceRef.MonitorClient())
{
    //WCF Service proxy
    proxy.Open();
    proxy.DoSomething();
}
```

Furthermore i have a Singleton class **DataAdapter** which is used in the WCF-service like this (most of the time it simply forwards the call to the DataAdapter, to be able to change the implementation of the actual data-access easily):

```
DataAdapter.GetInstance().DoSomething();
```

My DataAdapter looks like this and holds myData which should be kept alive:

```
public static DataAdapter DataAdapterInstance;
    private List<CustomObjects> myData;

    internal static ServiceAdapter GetInstance()
    {
        if (DataAdapterInstance == null)
        {
            DataAdapterInstance = new DataAdapter();
        }
        return DataAdapterInstance;
    }
```

Now here comes what im haveing trouble with: (im not sure if everything im writing here is correct)

- The windows service' runs theoretically forever (as it should)   The
- WCF-service only runs when it is called/created by my proxy (from
  asp.net)

When does my DataAdapter (which contains all my data) "die" ... so what im asking here is what is the lifetime of an object when there is actually no reference on it. (i would say its collected whenever the garbage collector runs)
 - I think my approach isnt too good, i would appreciate any suggestions on how to store my data (preferred without using a DB or external file)

Thank you for looking into my problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static references are "root" references for GC, so they will "never" die (until AppDomain is unloaded)

Comment: thank you! "never" sounds good :P
but what does "unload appDomain" mean?
is this in my scenario when the hosting windows service stops?

Comment: The application in .NET "consists" of AppDomains. Usually it is just one AppDomain unless you explicitly create more. Any [managed] code is executed in AppDomain. If you don't do anything with AppDomains, then you have just one and it is going to be unloaded once your application stops. In this scenario all the static variables are "alive" till the end.

Comment: By stop, does that mean when the app is manual stopped by being stopped and restarted (recycled) or OS shutdown etc? There wouldn't be any instances of the application stopping and starting due to inactivity?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `DataAdapterInstance` is static, it won't be collected until the `AppDomain` it's loaded in gets unloaded - which in most cases means that it will only get collected once your application closes.